# How to build a programmable LED strip?

Tags: microcontroller, led, circuit-design, microchip, electrical

I'm trying to build a home-made LED strip (non-RGB). It will be using single color SMD chips in array. The thought I have right now is to have 3 rows, each with about 15 or 25 same single color LEDs, will be sitting on custom design PCB board.

The goal is to have it programmable so I can set it to solid, flashing, sequential, and maybe even pickup a specific color (like only 1st and 3rd row lit up and others dimmed, or having 2nd row running sequential while 3rd row lit up solid). It will be run on 12V DC power and expected to be controlled with an arduino. I can ran some LED sequential just by arduino itself but I'm looking for something more efficient for running a large array.

What will be the best way to build it and what parts will I need? I'm new to circuit design and all information (like schematics and some basic knowledge) are welcomed. Thanks

edited:
To clarify, I basically want to build something like WS2812 with single color SMD LEDs, so I can have some high quality lighting and still have the programming flexibility like WS2812.

Comment: what about WS2811

Comment: I'm not sure if WS2811 or WS2812 can be used on non-RGB single color LED. Is it possible?

Comment: thw WS2811 chip can be used with any three LEDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to find a single color, high power, leds strip and command it using a uC (ex: arduino). I try to explain why.

The name WS2812 (and alike) refer to the chip inside the LED, not to the LED the chip is embedded in. In some early versions of those strips, the chips aren't embedded and you can see them on the strip. In theory you could buy those chips (or any other 1-wire communication chip) and add the LED yourself but the job is pretty nasty.

Going a bit more in detail. To power the LED you need a transistor, and the command the transistor you need a command channel. This channel can be 1-wire (ex: WS2812), Two Wires Interface (aka I2C), or more wires (example: SPI). Or you can make a complex matrix made of rows and columns, but then you might need to introduce extra diodes (ie: extra wiring complexity, extra soldering work) to avoid things like "ghosting".

Another chance is to connect multiple arduinos on the same I2C/SPI bus and use each GPIO for exactly 1 led only; you don't really need the whole arduino, you can use a bare minimal circuit to turn on a big AVR chip, or any other chip with many GPIOs. The atmega2560 have 60+ GPIOs (if I remember correctly); this means that you could individually address 60+ LEDs each atmega2560. So **you could embed 1 atmega1280 (or 2560) per each one of your 25-leds rows, directly on your pcb**.

But still, have you an idea of how much wiring complexity, and how much soldering work you'd have to do? If you can find an high power, single color, individually addressable leds, strip ... then connecting the strip (or mutiple strips) to an arduino is trivial. On my arduino nano v3 I'm controlling more than 300 (individually addressable) leds using 3 pins. But they are WS2813-clone strips (ie: RGB, and not high power).

In general, I'd leave the LEDS part to the machines, and configure the machined strips in the configuration I need. Just glue the strips on your pcb! :)

There's another problem then: heat. High power leds are soldered on aluminum boards because aluminum works as heatsink, or contact surface for a big heatsink. You can't find those high power leds mounted on flex-pcb because they would burn after 2 minutes of usage. So, if you are using high power leds, be sure to make your pcb in the proper way (ie: leave big, BIG, copper areas for dissipation purposes; and probably use those areas for connecting a bigger heatsink).

Comment: FYI you can actually put more than 126 LEDs on a single ATMEGA328 - the "LOL shield" was famous for this

Comment: @ChrisStratton from what I can see the LOL Shield is pcb only. It goes in the "matrix" part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It pretty much answered most of my concerns. Could you go into more detail on the atmega design, like what exactly I will need to have between the board and the LEDs (other than resistors)?

Comment: Between the atmega and the leds nothing (except resistors). But if you want for the leds to be individually addressable you must find an arduino that have enough GPIO in order to make your matrix or have each led on its own GPIO. You can use a multiple small atmega (ex: 328) on the same pcb,  or a big one (ex: 2560). In the case of multiple small atmegas, you need to interconnect them using I2C or SPI.